# Cannot generate previously working facebook open graph implementation

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have been trying to implement facebook publishing to timeline using open graph stories for a while now.

The call to FB.api gets done after returning from an ajax which creates an outfit/adds an item. It used to work smoothly for a while, and for other reasons (DOM related), the code had to be rewritten.

Suddenly, it doesn't work no matter what I do . I keep getting the error, 'This app is not granted the capability to use explicit sharing'. Keep in mind, it used to work ! and even this time around, it still worked for a bit, then flunked. I'm kind of at a loss here. The explicit sharing checkbox for the action has been checked for a long time already, and the circles next to the stories are fully green.

Could it be a bug or should I just submit a new and formal submission for approval ?

Any help with this would be appreciated as facebook have no formal recipient for such matters.